# How do you do the beading on a piece of furniture

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am working on an ornate stool and I do not know how to make the beading with out adding tens of thousands of extra faces. I will try anything at the moment
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get something like this:

[image]

you have to follow these steps:

1. Shift-A -> Curve -> Curve Spirals

If you don't have that menu, go to your preferences and check the add-on:

[image]

[image]

2. change settings to:

[image]

3. Shift A -> Curve -> Circle and make it bigger

[image]

4. select your spiral -> object -> convert to mesh

[image]

5. add skin and subdivision modifiers

[image]

6. add curve modifier

[image]

[image]

7. material setup:

[image]

video tutorial for modeling:  https://youtu.be/Ea4T0VUUA-k

Comment: I have tried for about 2 hours but when I go to select the circle blender dose not let me use it. Thank you getting this sorted out will be a life saver.

Comment: at what step do you have problems?

Comment: i added a video tutorial link for the modeling at the end of my answer

Answer (score 2):

To save geometry, this could well be a place for a bump-map. The advantages of  geometry, (or displacement-geometry at render time) over bump are roughly:

- Visible profile / external contour. Not the case here: the beading is tucked in.
- Parallax / occlusion.. where one bump conceals another. We don't have the viewing angle for that, here.
- Shadowing. Bump simulates the light-response of the surface, but the bumps don't cast shadows. The difference here is slight:

[image]

Left: Bump only, Right: Displacement only.

To use Bump, you would have to make a height-map of your beading. You could model your beading as shown by @Chris, and shoot a tileable map, as shown, for example, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191286/35559). But as I was doing that, I thought it would be good to have at least a basic 'Beading' shader node-group, to generate the heights procedurally.

The group is based on a semicircular wave:

[image]

.. where, by Pythagoras, `Y = sqrt(Radius^2 - X^2)`. This could be done by putting a Ping Pong wave through a color-ramp, but then the rounded ends in 3D would be fiddly. (At the hemispherical ends, `Height = sqrt(Radius^2 - (X^2 + Y^2))`.

The group looks like this, inside:

[image]

Sorry about the tangle, squishing into screen-capture doesn't help.

Eventually, in these examples, it's used like this:

[image]

The *Gradient* node is just to wrap X around the outside of the cylinder's Object Space. You could UV unwrap instead.

The interface isn't silky-smooth; that would take more nodes. *Radius* sets the thickness of the elements, *Tilt*: the slope, *Length* and *Y-Scale* work against one another.. the higher the *Y-Scale*, the flatter the ends of the elements. *Floor* raises a base-level from which the elements protrude, making gaps.

Between them, the parameters can achieve a fair variety of effects .. (All these are Bump only, no Displacement):

[image]

The top example puts the output of the group through a color-ramp, for the fancy detail.

[image]